# MVC 5 Convert SQL Query to EF Linq

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this result:
[image]

The problem is that I am not using the power of EF.

I followed [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx) EF tutorial but i'm now able to do it.

ActivityLogController.cs

```
using System;
...

namespace AccountSystem.Controllers
{
    public class ActivityLogController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: ActivityLog
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            /* var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var Emaill = (from x in db.Users
                          where x.Id == id
                         select x.Email).Single(); */



            //string Access = AccessQ.ToString();

            IEnumerable<ActivityLogViewData> model = null;
            List<ActivityLogViewData> verify = new List<ActivityLogViewData>();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("xxx");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", connection);
            command.CommandText = "select dbo.AspNetUsers.Email,dbo.AspNetUsers.UserName,dbo.ActivityLogModels.ID,dbo.ActivityLogModels.Acess,dbo.AspNetUsers.Id from dbo.ActivityLogModels inner join dbo.AspNetUsers on dbo.ActivityLogModels.userID=dbo.AspNetUsers.Id";
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                verify.Add(new ActivityLogViewData { Email = dr[0].ToString(), UserName = dr[1].ToString(), accessID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString()), Acess = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3].ToString()), userID = dr[4].ToString()});
            }
            connection.Close();
            //verify.Add(new ActivityLogViewData {Email = Emaill });
            //return View(db.ActivityLog.ToList());
            return View(verify);
        }
```

The commented lines are my unsuccessful tries.

Can someone convert this to use EF?

TiA!

Comment: If you are talking about email query, it looks fine. What is the error you see?

Comment: To assign my "EF" query to email, i needed to use .Single() on query, that only return 1 value. I want all and in the next step, i want filters. The "Verify" return a list because the while cycle I use on my "hardcoded query". @Andrei